# Instrumentation of android apps

Tags: android, instrumentation

I'm very new in testing and instrumentation, especially for Android, so please forgive me if my question will sounds odd.

I read something about **dexmaker** but I didn't understand how it works. Let's make an example...

I just have to know if I can do this:

1. Assume we have a classical hello world application, nothing
   special, just print on the screen "Hello World"
2. We totally ignore how it's coded, we can just see what happen on the screen
3. Can I code something to examine what's going on, collect info about, and (for example) "Hello guys" make appear instead of "Hello world" on the application?

Any hint will be appreciated :)

Comment: I certainly hope Android is safe from such types of code injection...

Answer (score 0):

you can try dex2jar scripts to extract sort of java code out of apk file, though its not always accurate.

Comment: At the moment i don't need to extract java code from the .dex file ... but i need to code a program receiving a .dex file as input, read it, parse it, and modify a specific part of it, such as a private String or stuff like that